# Не понятно или непонятно

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно? "Но опять не понятно какого цвета они будут" или "Но опять непонятно какого цвета они будут"? И запятая после непонятно нужна?

Comment: Запятая конечно нужна! Лучше слитно.

Comment: Если ваше предложение аналогично такому:
"Но опять не было понятно, какого цвета они будут", то можно и раздельно писать.

Answer (score 2):

***Но опять непонятно, какого цвета они будут.***

Написание НЕ **слитное**, нет логически подчеркнутого отрицания.

Запятая ставится **в сложноподчиненом предложение с придаточным изъяснительным**. Придаточное относится к предикативному наречию в роли сказуемого в главном предложении, союзное слово "какого".

Comment: При постановке минуса за ответ просьба указывать, какие ошибки в нем допущены (тогда я их исправлю, а вас поблагодарю за подсказку).  Иначе же это будет необоснованная минусовка и повод для обращения к модераторам, а этого не хотелось бы.

Comment: Впрочем, я заглянула в комментарий к вопросу и примерно поняла, каковы претензии.  Автор комментария ищет смысловые оттенки, занимается конструированием новых аналогичных предложений, но при этом не учитывает, что работать надо с заданным предложением. Это в нем мы делаем выбор, а там отрицание интонационно не выразишь, так как на наречие в конце первой фразы падает обычное тоническое ударение (оно всегда ставится на последнее слово). Можно иметь  и высказывать любое свое мнение, а вот минусовать чужое  без абсолютной уверенности в его некорректности не следует.